# How can I rollback transaction in microservice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Im trying to build a system by creating microservices base on **spring-cloud**. Refer(https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring) 
I update something new:

**application 1:**(http://localhost:3333/accounts) 
Request body:

```
{
    "id":"123",
    "number":"223",
    "owner":"888",
    "balance":"100"
}
```

*-WebAccountsController.java*

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/accounts")
        public void insertAccount(@RequestBody Account account){
            accountsService.createAccount(account);
        }
```

*-WebAccountsService.java*

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = NullPointerException.class)
    public void createAccount(Account account) {
        try {
            account.setOwner(account.getOwner()+System.currentTimeMillis()%1000);
            HttpEntity<Account> request = new HttpEntity<Account>(account);
            System.out.println("==================="+account.getOwner());
            String url=serviceUrl + "/create-accounts";
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( url, request , String.class );
            String s = null;
            s.equalsIgnoreCase("asa");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

**application 2:** ((http://localhost:2222/create-accounts)

*-AccountsController.java*

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create-accounts")
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void createAccount(@RequestBody Account account) throws Exception {
        try {
            logger.info("========================================================= " + account.getOwner());
            accountRepository.save(account);
            logger.info("accounts-service byNumber() found: " + account);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

In the test case, how can I rollback data if there is exception? 
in WebAccountsService.java (application 1), after calling the API webapplication 2, an exception happened. How can I rollback the result from invoking api create-accounts which belongs application2 (The record which was created from previous process will be deleted)? 
U also try to run (https://github.com/haipv2/microservices-demo-master)
Thanks!!!

Comment: In the way you present it, i just would 'manually' handle it.
You've a try catch block in Application1,  so just catch the exception, and call application2 (new endpoint), to delete the account just created

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I want to find out new mechanism, dont do it manually.

Comment: Understood, you can have a look here also : http://www.baeldung.com/transactions-across-microservices

Comment: yep, i read it. it's all theory. I am looking for an example which I can run it :). Beside using Queue or Store State DB to store data before commit data, i wonder that is spring cloud able to resolve the problem?